# Menu resise to child elements on hover css

Tags: css, button, drop-down-menu, resize

ok what have i done wrong here i want the main button not to resise to child elements on mouse over, and with dropdown menu problem i have is buttons on the main menu resise to the dropdown width on hover im a noob so sorry if its a dumb question and i apologise in advance if this has allready been answered somewhere else tried to find the answer but its easyer finding out how to put it together than finding out what is messing up what
heres the css ;

```
     #menu 
     {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    height:50px;
    width:1000px;

}
#menu ul {
    height:30px;
margin-left: 0px;
 padding:0;
    }
#menu ul li {
    height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
    padding-right:0px;
    margin:0;
    }
#menu ul li a { 
height:30px; 
padding:0 15px 0 15px; 
text-shadow: none;
 line-height:30px;
  color:#fff;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:17px;
   font-weight:normal;
    }
#menu ul li.active {
    height:30px;
    margin:0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }
 #menu ul li.active a{
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
     height:30px;
    color:#880000;
     text-shadow:#000;
     background:#000044;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; webkit-radius: 5px;
}
#menu ul li.active a, #menu ul li a:hover {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:30px;
    color:#880000;
    text-shadow:#000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; webkit-radius: 5px;

    }

      #menu ul li:hover {
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; webkit-radius: 5px;
}
```

The child elements

```
#menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    width:180px;
    left:-999em;
    border-top:0;
     margin:0px;
      padding:0; 
      -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;

      }
              #menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul 
              {
           display: block;  
            position:relative;
            top:4px; 
             left:-0px;
              z-index:6;
               background-color:#444444;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
                   }
            #menu ul li ul li {
       padding: 0; 
      height:auto;
     width:180px;
     margin:0px;
   border:none;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
    }
    #menu ul li ul li a:hover ul {
color:880000;
background-color:#444444;
-moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
}
    #menu ul li:hover ul li a {
 background-color:#444444;
  text-shadow:none;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
  }
     #menu ul li:hover ul li {
 background-color:#444444; 
     -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
          }
       #menu ul li:hover ul li a, #menu ul li ul li a, #menu ul li.active ul li a
            {
      margin:0px;
          padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
          height:24px;
          line-height:24px; 
          background:#555;
           border-bottom:1px solid #3a3a3a;
           color:#ffffff;
            background-color:#444444;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:normal;
             text-shadow:none;
           -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; webkit-radius: 0px;
                }
           #menu ul li ul li a:hover, #menu ul li ul li.active a, #menu ul li.active     ul li a:hover,#menu ul li.active ul li.active a {
           line-height:24px;
            background:#343434;
           color:#880000; 
           font-size:12px;
          text-shadow:#000;
           }
           #menu ul li ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul ul ul 
            a{
       display:none; 
             }
            #menu ul li ul li ul li{
          height:24;
        width:180px;
         border:none; 
        text-align: left;
          left:180px;}

          #menu ul li ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul ul ul ul:hover 
              {
                  }
                    #menu ul li ul li ul li
                     {
                       height:24;
                      width:180px;
                      border:none; 
                   text-align: left;
                   left:180px;
               }
```

please bear in mind its not finished yet i still have to add the styles for the second child menu
    thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Child element should be absolutely positioned. Otherwise, it will just stretch out its surrounding element (in this case, your parent menu item).